# NPM Install Error in installing ReactNative CLI

Tags: react-native, expo

I wish to install the React Native CLI to my Windows 10 x64 PC. Kindly help.

I encounter the following error when I issue this command:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

**The error I receive:**

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-cli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.21.35:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:2623)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-cli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.21.35:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:2623)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR!   message:
npm ERR!    'request to http://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-cli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.21.35:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:2623)',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-cli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.21.35:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:2623)\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-fetch-npm\\src\\index.js:68:14)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)\n    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mwaqa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-11T14_13_07_498Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be related to your proxy, first, try these following commands:

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and then execute

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed on your system?

Comment: No, I even have Windows Defender disabled.

Comment: Have you tried executing all commands with admin user right? If not please try.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run from both the CMD and PowerShell as Adminsitrator privileges but it still returns the same error.